# Remove stack frame setup/initilization

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, clang

I have the following program:

```
void main1() {
    ((void(*)(void)) (0xabcdefabcdef)) ();
}
```

I create it with the following commands:

```
clang -fno-stack-protector -c -static -nostdlib -fpic  -fpie -O0 -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables main.c -o shellcode.o
ld shellcode.o -o shellcode -S -static -dylib -e main1 -order_file order.txt
gobjcopy -O binary --only-section=.text shellcode shellcode.output
```

The assembly looks like the following:

```
                             //
                             // ram 
                             // ram: 00000000-00000011
                             //
                             **************************************************************
                             *                          FUNCTION                          *
                             **************************************************************
                             undefined FUN_00000000()
             undefined         AL:1           <RETURN>
                             FUN_00000000
        00000000 55              PUSH       RBP
        00000001 48 89 e5        MOV        RBP,RSP
        00000004 48 b8 ef        MOV        RAX,0xabcdefabcdef
                 cd ab ef 
                 cd ab 00 00
        0000000e ff d0           CALL       RAX
        00000010 5d              POP        RBP
        00000011 c3              RET
```

How do I get clang to remove the `PUSH RBP`, `MOV RBP,RSP` and `POP RBP` instructions as they are unnecessary?

I can do this if I write the program in assembly with the following lines:

```
.globl start
start:
    movq $0xabcdefabcdef, %rax
    call *%rax
    ret
```

and with the following build commands:

```
clang  -static -nostdlib main.S -o crashme.o
gobjcopy -O binary --only-section=.text crashme.o crashme.output
```

and the resulting assembly:

```
                             //
                             // ram 
                             // ram: 00000000-0000000c
                             //
             assume DF = 0x0  (Default)
        00000000 48 b8 ef        MOV        RAX,0xabcdefabcdef
                 cd ab ef 
                 cd ab 00 00
        0000000a ff d0           CALL       RAX
        0000000c c3              RET
```

but I would much rather write C code instead of assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to enable optimization. Any optimization level like `-O3` enables `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

It will also optimize the tailcall into a `jmp` instead of `call`/`ret` though.  If you need to avoid that for some reason, maybe you can use `-fomit-frame-pointer` at the default `-O0`.

For shellcode you might want `-Os` to optimize for code size.  Or even clang's `-Oz`; that will have a side-effect of avoiding some `0` bytes in the machine code by using `push imm8` / `pop reg` to put small constants in registers, instead of `mov reg, imm32`.

Comment: `-fomit-frame-pointer` did the trick. It did add a `push RAX` and `pop RAX` however.

Comment: @twodayslate: yes, to align the stack by 16 before the call, as required by the ABI.  That's why you should enable optimization so it can use a `jmp` tailcall.  Or possibly you could compile with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=3` (2^3=8 instead of the default 2^4=16).  [gcc -mpreferred-stack-boundary option](//stackoverflow.com/q/10251203)